# If a problem is inapproximable for $(2-\epsilon)$, can we conclude there exists no PTAS for it?

Tags: computational-complexity, approximation-algorithms

If we prove that:

*The existance of a $(2-\epsilon)$-approximation algorithm for Problem P1 implies $P = NP$*,

can we conclude:

*There exists no PTAS for Problem P1, and so P1 is APX-hard*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can conclude **There exists no PTAS for Problem P1 if $P \neq NP$**, but you can **NOT** conclude *P1 is APX-hard*. Precisely:

1. If someone proofs $P = NP$ you get a trivial PTAS;
2. Assumung $P \neq NP$, it still could be APX-intermediate (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APX#APX-intermediate).

Comment: Thanks. So, based on the Wiki page, we cannot expect to find a PTAS for Problem P1, but it doesn't mean it is APS-hard. Am I right?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: So, I edit your answer based on that.